# java add array argument with syntax "..." into a list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

i want to cache all the ids in the parameter method into a list. I try this, but compiler error

```
private List<Integer> idsCache = new ArrayList<>();
...
String getSomeObject(int... ids) {
    this.idsCache.addAll(ids);
    ...
}
```

how can i add an ... array argument to a list in java?

I also tried it with `this.idsCache.addAll(Arrays.asList(ids));`

Can i do it without change the typ of ids?

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

idsCache.addAll(Arrays.asList(ids));

EDIT: Above solution does not work. Here's a Java 8 solution which boxes the primitives:

```
idsCache.addAll(Arrays.stream(ids).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Compiler error: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that int[] conforms to Integer inference variable T has incompatible bounds: lower bounds: int[] upper bound ....

Comment: if `ids` is of type `int` doesn't work. Must be Integer, as per Deadpool's answer

Comment: Can i do it without change the type of ids?

Comment: no you can't Collections can only have objects @emoleumassi

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a primitive type you have to do something like below.

```
String getSomeObject(int... ids) {
  for (int id : ids) {
    this.idsCache.add(id);
  }
}
```

Or you can change your function to take an Integer.

```
String getSomeObject(Integer... ids) {
    this.idsCache.addAll(id);
}
```